# I'm getting XcmPallet.Unreachable error in parity-bridges-common

Tags: xcm, xcmp, parity-bridges-common

I'm transferring assets from one chain to another through XCM , it is showing Unreachable. But when i transferring through script in the terminal then also my account balance on one chain is debited but it is not credited on another account on different chain .

Can please someone guide me through Unreachable error and the token-transfer mechanism

[image]

Comment: Which script are you following from terminal?

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is that the `dest` argument is not correctly defined.

I assume you are trying to that account you show there but in another chain. You are missing identifying the chain where this account should receive the funds. An interior defined like `X2 { paraid, account}` would look a bit better to me.

But this question could use some more detail in general. Are these two parachains connected to a relaychain?, the same relaychain ?